# Checking for selector duplicates in a css file with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, regex

I have a string with CSS selectors in it like this (Actually a file, but it will be a string after I read it in):

```
.u-br {
   blah blah
}

.u-tr {
    blah .blah
}

....
.u-mr { }
```

What I need to do is check the selectors (the `.u-tr` part to make sure that there are no collisions / duplicates.

Something like:

```
let selectorArray = process(stringOfCSS);
```

The selector array should now contain:

```
['u-br', 'u-mr', etc]
```

At this point I just need to make sure all entries in the array are unique which I know how to do.

Comment: Could you just put all the abbreviated selectors together in one place sorted alphabetically?

Comment: [The postcss build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli) puts them all together, and I could then sort them and resave them, and scan manually for duplicates, but given that it's me :) ... I might still miss something ...

Comment: So you want to make sure `.u-tr` has not been occured in file already?

Comment: @Ole If you might still miss something, it seems to me to be a good exercise for improving organizational skills / slowing down and doing things methodically... It's a valuable skill :)

Comment: Can't you just do a quick search with your ide?

Comment: Yes - since I'm covering utilities for text, borders, margin, positioning, I may accidentally create a duplicate abbreviation ...

Comment: @KevinB I have a [lot of repositories](https://github.com/superflycss) and will be adding a lot more so that could get very slow ...

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm 40 repositories into this and now you tell me :)

Comment: Could you cache all selectors somewhere in a file? This way you will be able to work with arrays too.

Comment: @Ole use this as a detox / addiction breaker: use the time you'd otherwise be playing fortnite to get this done :)

Comment: @revo it should be pretty easy to parse all the selectors and put them in an array.  That's all the question is asking for.  I could do what you are saying, but first I have to get them into the array.  Once they are in the array I know how to check for duplicates.

Comment: So what you are stuck at is finding a regex to extract all selectors? At the moment it is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I would be the dad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVmCA4kl50Y

Comment: @revo so if I have a string of CSS with a lot of selector in it, how do I filter out the selectors and put them in an array?

Comment: Also all the rules are in a CSS file.  Not in the browser.  These rules are being produced by a build process.

Comment: Does it mean yes or no to my question?

Comment: @revo I simplied the question.  Is it clearer now?

Comment: Unless it means something else. Try `\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/BSefzJ/1

Comment: @revo - Nice!  I should be able to finish the rest myself with that.  I'll have to experiment a bit.  Thank you!

Comment: @revo if you want to put that in an answer I'll add the javascript later and give you credit for the answer.

Comment: If you put it all into a single string, you can use a simple regex to remove the duplicates. However, this way will remove the duplicates from the top down. Something like Find `/\.(selector-[^{}]*?)\s*\{[^{}]*\}(?=[\S\s]*?\.\1\s*\{[^{}]*\})/` replace with nothing. It ends up containing only unique selectors.

Comment: @sln I'll be adding that to the toolbox as well - thanks - Wanted to understand the regex answers fully - and this tutorial helped a lot: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: @Ole - That's a nice cheat sheet. When you're ready to explore regex fully, use this [RegexFprmat](http://www.regexformat.com). It will take you from novice to expert in a matter of a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let s = `.u-br, .u-nr {
    blah blah
}

.u-tr {
    blah .blah
}`;
let selectors = s.match(/\.-?[_a-zA-Z]+[\w-]*(?=[^{}]*\{)/g);

function hasDuplicates(array) {
    return (new Set(array)).size !== array.length;
}
console.log(hasDuplicates(selectors));//false;

//Find the duplicates
var sorted_arr = selectors.slice().sort();

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you. First I'm creating the array of the css rules in the first stylesheet: `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules`.

Next I'm iterating over the rules and if the rule begins with "." I console.log it. No need to check for the `{`. I hope this may help you.

```js
let stylesArray = Array.from(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules);

stylesArray.forEach(rule =>{  
  if(rule.selectorText.substring(0, 1) == "."){console.log(rule.selectorText)}
})
```

```css
.u-top-right {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.u-tr {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
#test{display:none}

.test{display:flex;}
```

Comment: It's close, but unfortunately I cant use this, because I need to run it in Node as part of the build process.

Answer (score -1):

You can write something like this to loop through and pull each classname individually. As it finds each one, if the classname hasn't been found yet, it's added as a key to `output`, otherwise it will increment the value of `output[classname]`. Anything returning a value over 1 will be a duplicate property.

```js
let input = `.u-top-right {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.u-tr {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}.u-top-right {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.u-tr {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}.u-top-right {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.u-tr {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}.u-top-right {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}

.random-classname {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}`

const rgx = /\.(.+?)\s*\{\s*/,
  output = {}
let match
  
while((match = rgx.exec(input))){
  let classname = match[1]
  if(!output[classname]) output[classname] = 0
  ++output[classname]
  input = input.replace(rgx, '')
}

console.log(output)
```